# Enable OpenMP support

Tags: c++, openmp, intel-mpi

I have installed [Intel MPI](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mpi-library) on my Windows machine.

Quoting section 2.2 of [FLANN library documentation](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/research/flann/uploads/FLANN/flann_manual-1.8.4.pdf):

> the project that uses FLANN needs to be compiled with a compiler that
>   supports the OpenMP standard and the OpenMP support must be enabled.
>   The number of cores to be used can be selected with the cores in
>   the SearchParams structure. By default a single core will be used.
>   Setting the cores eld to zero will automatically use as many threads
>   as cores available on the machine.

Since I never used neither Intel MPI or OpenMP, I don't know if it's ok to use the first one for this case and what "OpenMP support must be enabled" means.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Could you please check this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139468/cmake-doesnt-recognize-openmpi?noredirect=1#comment61820817_37139468

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Intel MPI is not a compiler. If you're looking for a compiler, try the [Intel C++ Compiler](https://software.intel.com/en-us/c-compilers) or [MinGW](http://mingw-w64.org/doku.php). OpenMP are integrated with these compilers, you just need to enable them with a switch. For Intel it's `/Qopenmp`. For GCC (MinGW) it's `-fopenmp`.

Comment: This is weird, since before the Intel MPI installation CMake could not detect any OpenMP support and now it does

Comment: @justHelloWorld, I guess you have Intel compilers installed too but they are not in the path. The library you are building is picking up the compiler wrapper(s) from Intel MPI and thus the Intel compiler(s).

Comment: @HristoIliev Could you please check this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37139468/cmake-doesnt-recognize-openmpi?noredirect=1#comment61820817_37139468

Comment: @justHelloWorld, I'm sorry, I have zero understanding of CMake.